# MySQL gives error in creating MySQL-Events

Tags: mysql, schedule, mysql-event

I am trying to create one MySQL event which updates the table at every midnight.
My query is like this:

```
CREATE EVENT postdetails_change_status 

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2014-04-21 00:00:00'

DO BEGIN

    UPDATE postdetails SET status = 'completed' WHERE DeleteDate < CURDATE();

END;
```

This gives me error like[image]

But when I run this update query normally, it works perfectly. Please help.

Reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is correct but just change delimiter before script execution.
try below:

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT postdetails_change_status 

ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2014-04-21 00:00:00'

DO BEGIN

    UPDATE postdetails SET status = 'completed' WHERE DeleteDate < CURDATE();

END |

delimiter ;
```